# How to delete Skype lists that were originally Messenger Groups?

Tags: windows, skype, contacts, windows-live-messenger

**First, some notes:**

- I know how to delete **lists** that I have created in Skype.
- I know how to delete **groups** that I have created in Skype.
- I know how to delete **contacts**, both Skype contacts and Messenger contacts. They remain deleted.
- "Messenger groups" and "Skype lists" are contact lists created to organize contacts.
- "Skype groups" are conference-like conversations between multiple people. "Messenger groups" **do not** mean this.
- I am using regular Windows Desktop version of Skype, i.e. version 7.8.80.102.
- I have Android Skype 6.1.0.16416. I did not find a function to delete lists in the app, but I can see them.

**Problem:**

- Once upon a time, there was MSN Messenger. It became Windows Live Messenger. *Hereafter known simply as Messenger.*
- I had several contacts and I organized them by creating more than a dozen Messenger groups.
- I had also created a separate Skype account (which I seldom used in the beginning).
- Time passed and Messenger was retired by Microsoft. My Messenger account was merged with my Skype account. I stopped using Messenger and permanently migrated to Skype.
- More time passed, and I eventually deleted a lot of the old Messenger contacts. I had only kept a handful, and deleted the rest. The original groups became unnecessary, but **they were not visible in Skype anyway**.
- After some time, the original Messenger groups **re-appeared** in Skype as "lists", hereafter known as *zombie lists*. (I also have pure Skype lists that I created to organize Skype contacts.).
- These new "lists" that are re-appeared Messenger groups are now mostly blank. Some have just one contact. *This is because I deleted most Messenger contacts previously.*
- I can delete these zombie lists in Skype. I know how. Just select the list, and click the trash icon next to it. And it's gone.
- But some 10-15 minutes after I delete all these zombie lists, **they come back!** Even the one contact that I had removed from some of the lists will return to the list.
- I noticed that if I rename one of these zombie lists, after 10-15 minutes, the name reverts to the original (as it was in the Messenger days).

How do I really *REALLY **REALLY*** get rid of these zombie lists?

Comment: I too have the same issue, across multiple platforms (Windows 10, OS X)

Comment: @JeremyCade Check my answer. Your comment prompted me to think in that angle and explore it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bit of exploring and found the solution. So far the groups have not come back.

1. Go to [People app website](https://people.live.com/) and sign in to your Microsoft account (same account that you use for Skype).
2. Make sure you are signed in to Skype Desktop as well.
3. In the People site, on the left side, find each Skype list (Messenger group; *hereafter called "group"*) you want to remove.

   - *For ease of searching, try disabling some of the contact types (such as Outlook, Skype, Messenger) in the Settings menu until only the groups you want to remove are mostly shown. The menu appears when you click the gear icon near your name on top right.*
4. Click on the group, so the contacts (if any) are listed on right.
5. Click on Delete in the top bar, then click on Delete in the popup to confirm.

   [image: screenshot showing how to delete contact list (group) in People app]

   - *Note that the deleted group may still appear in the left list - this is a bug of People app. If you reload the site, it will go away.*
6. Go to Skype Desktop's Contacts pane, and open the group.
7. Click on the Delete icon near the group name, and click Delete button to confirm.

   [image: screenshot showing how to delete contact list (group) in Skype desktop]
8. Repeat the two delete actions (steps 3 to 7) for each group you want to remove.

Comment: Confirmed working. After 16 hours, the zombies are still gone. Reflects on Skype Android too. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem: I could change lists' names and could change contacts from list to list, and everything remained - but if I deleted a list it would reappear.

Deleting the lists from http://people.live.com wouldn't avoid the problem of deleting lists in Skype and reappearing (only in the Skype app).

I finally managed to delete the lists simply by deleting them one by one, and giving enough time from the deletion of one list until I deleted the next one (about 20 minutes).

That way, all lists have disappeared. I just deleted one list each time I remembered about Skype while I was working on something else.